# how to fix spinnig beach ball of death in Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, loops, tkinter

I am trying to make RPS (rock paper scissor) in Tkinter. My code works completely fine until I press the OK button, when I do that, I get the spinning loading icon thingy (MacOS). I tried to look at my cpu in the activity monitor and it was TROUGH THE ROOF  (100% cpu usage)

I have tried to google the issue  and i added `time.sleep(0.2)` but it didn't work

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

def rock():
    masterrock = Tk()

    rl = Label(masterrock, text="rock, paper or scissor")
    rl.grid(row=0, column=1)

    rb = Button(masterrock, text="OK", command=lambda: rock2())
    rb.grid(row=2, column=1)

    player1 = Entry(masterrock)
    player1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    global player
    player = (player1.get())

    t = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]

    global computer
    computer = t[randint(0, 2)]
    
def rock2():
    s = True
    while s == True:

        if player == computer:
            gllabel = Label(masterrock, text="tie")
            gllabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

        elif player == "rock":

            if computer == "paper":
                gllabel1 = Label(masterrock, text="you lose!")
                gllabel1.grid(row=2, column=1)

            else:
                gllabel2 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
                gllabel2.grid(row=2, column=1)


        elif player == "paper":
            if computer == "scissor":
                gllabel3 = Label(masterrock, text="You lose")
                gllabel3.grid(row=2, column=1)

            else:
                gllabel4 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
                gllabel4.grid(row=2, column=1)

        elif player == "scissor":

            if computer == "rock":

                gllabel5 = Label(masterrock, text="You lose")
                gllabel5.grid(row=2, column=1)

            else:
                gllabel6 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
                gllabel6.grid(row=2, column=1)

    time.sleep(0.2)

mainloop()
```

I am only 14 so my code may be a bit sloppy. Thx in adnvance

Comment: Create a tkinter loop using `<tkinter.Tk>.after(time_in_ms, function)`

Comment: sound good, but where do i put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]

def rock():
    global computer, masterrock, player_entry, ok_button
    masterrock = Tk()

    options_label = Label(masterrock, text="rock, paper or scissor")
    options_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    ok_button = Button(masterrock, text="OK", command=rock2)
    ok_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

    player_entry = Entry(masterrock)
    player_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    computer = options[randint(0, 2)]

def rock2():
    player = player_entry.get()
    if player in options:
        player_entry.config(bg="white")
    else:
        player_entry.config(bg="red")
        return None # Stop if the user input was invalid
    ok_button.destroy()
    if player == computer:
        gllabel = Label(masterrock, text="tie")
        gllabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            gllabel1 = Label(masterrock, text="you lose!")
            gllabel1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        else:
            gllabel2 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
            gllabel2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "scissor":
            gllabel3 = Label(masterrock, text="You lose")
            gllabel3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        else:
            gllabel4 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
            gllabel4.grid(row=2, column=1)

    elif player == "scissor":
        if computer == "rock":
            gllabel5 = Label(masterrock, text="You lose")
            gllabel5.grid(row=2, column=1)

        else:
            gllabel6 = Label(masterrock, text="You win!")
            gllabel6.grid(row=2, column=1)


global masterrock
rock()
masterrock.mainloop()
```

There were a few things wrong with your code.

First it isn't good practice to call `mainloop()` directly. It is better to use `<tkinter.Tk>.mainloop()`.

Also in your code `player1.get()` runs just after `player1 = Entry(masterrock)` so the user hasn't had enough time to actually write their response.

You never considered the user giving you faulty input like `"#"`. Never trust the user input. Always check if it is something that you expect.

You don't actually need a loop. `<tkinter.Tk>.mainloop()` is a loop. For more info read [this](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/).